# Footer not showing up on webpage, but i can see it when page loads

Tags: html, css, footer

I have a page I created that shows up funky when its loaded on the web. My footer is not showing up. Though I can see it flicker on the screen briefly.  Is there something in my code that may be throwing it off?

Here is the HTML

```
<div id="pageheader">
    <img src="Assets/OLE logo.jpg" alt="https://olehealth123.sharepoint.com" />
    <p>
        <a href="https://interland3.donorperfect.net/weblink/weblink.aspx?name=E161841&id=1">Donate to OLE


        </a>
    </p>
</div>
```

```
        <!--CS: Start Ribbon Snippet-->
        <!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
        <!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="wssucw" TagName="Welcome" Src="~/_controltemplates/15/Welcome.ascx"%>-->
        <!--MS:<SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server" HideFromSearchCrawler="true" EmitDiv="true">-->
            <div id="TurnOnAccessibility" style="display:none" class="s4-notdlg noindex">
                <a id="linkTurnOnAcc" href="#" class="ms-accessible ms-acc-button" onclick="SetIsAccessibilityFeatureEnabled(true);UpdateAccessibilityUI();document.getElementById('linkTurnOffAcc').focus();return false;">
                    <!--MS:<SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="&#60;%$Resources:wss,master_turnonaccessibility%&#62;" EncodeMethod="HtmlEncode">-->
                    <!--ME:</SharePoint:EncodedLiteral>-->
                </a>
            </div>
            <div id="TurnOffAccessibility" style="display:none" class="s4-notdlg noindex">
                <a id="linkTurnOffAcc" href="#" class="ms-accessible ms-acc-button" onclick="SetIsAccessibilityFeatureEnabled(false);UpdateAccessibilityUI();document.getElementById('linkTurnOnAcc').focus();return false;">
                    <!--MS:<SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="&#60;%$Resources:wss,master_turnoffaccessibility%&#62;" EncodeMethod="HtmlEncode">-->
                    <!--ME:</SharePoint:EncodedLiteral>-->
                </a>
            </div>
        <!--ME:</SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>-->
        <div id="ms-designer-ribbon">
            <!--SID:02 {Ribbon}-->
            <!--PS: Start of READ-ONLY PREVIEW (do not modify) --><div class="DefaultContentBlock" style="background:rgb(0, 114, 198); color:white; width:100%; padding:8px; height:64px; overflow:hidden;">The SharePoint ribbon will be here when your file is either previewed on or applied to your site.</div><!--PE: End of READ-ONLY PREVIEW -->
        </div>
        <!--MS:<SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server" AuthenticationRestrictions="AnonymousUsersOnly">-->
            <!--MS:<wssucw:Welcome runat="server" EnableViewState="false">-->
            <!--ME:</wssucw:Welcome>-->
        <!--ME:</SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>-->
        <!--CE: End Ribbon Snippet-->
        <div id="s4-workspace">
            <div id="s4-bodyContainer">
                <div id="menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="https://olehealth123.sharepoint.com/">Home


                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <!--closing the main li tag-->
                    </ul>
                    <!--end of main ul tag-->
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Admin


                            </a>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Human Resources


                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Finance


                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">OLE Health Foundation


                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Marketing &amp; Communications


                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <!--closure of inner ul tag-->
                        </li>
                        <!--closing the main li tag-->
                    </ul>
                    <!--end of main ul tag-->
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Clinical Operations


                            </a>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Operations Homepage


                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Calistoga


                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">1100 Trancas


                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">County Campus


                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Fairfield


                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Napa Pear Tree Lane


                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Clinical Pharmacy


                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Integrated Primary Care


                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Behavioral Health


                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <!--closure of inner ul tag-->
                        </li>
                        <!--closing the main li tag-->
                    </ul>
                    <!--end of main ul tag-->
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Committees


                            </a>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="https://olehealth123.sharepoint.com/QICommittee">QI Committee


                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="https://olehealth123.sharepoint.com/ecwcommittee/">eCW Optimization Committee


                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="https://olehealth123.sharepoint.com/strategicplancommittees">Strategic Planning Committees


                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="https://olehealth123.sharepoint.com/Quality Assurance Committees ">Quality Assurance Committees


                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="https://olehealth123.sharepoint.com/Workgroups">Workgroups


                                    </a>
                                </li>
                <li>
                                    <a href="https://olehealth123.sharepoint.com/Charters">Charters


                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <!--closure of inner ul tag-->
                        </li>
                        <!--closing the main li tag-->
                    </ul>
                    <!--end of main ul tag-->
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Leadership Teams


                            </a>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="https://olehealth123.sharepoint.com/Executive%20Leadership%20Team">Executive Leadership Team


                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="https://olehealth123.sharepoint.com/Operations%20Leadership%20Team">Operations Leadership Team


                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="https://olehealth123.sharepoint.com/Clinical%20Leadership%20Team">Clinical Leadership Team


                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <!--closure of inner ul tag-->
                        </li>
                        <!--closing the main li tag-->
                    </ul>
                    <!--end of main ul tag-->
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Patient Services


                            </a>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Link 1


                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Link 1


                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Link 1


                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Link 1


                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <!--closure of inner ul tag-->
                        </li>
                        <!--closing the main li tag-->
                    </ul>
                    <!--end of main ul tag-->
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Facilities


                            </a>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Link 1


                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Link 1


                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Link 1


                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Link 1


                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <!--closure of inner ul tag-->
                        </li>
                        <!--closing the main li tag-->
                    </ul>
                    <!--end of main ul tag-->
                </div>
                <!--end of main menu div-->
                <div data-name="ContentPlaceHolderMain">
                    <!--CS: Start PlaceHolderMain Snippet-->
                    <!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
                    <!--MS:<SharePoint:AjaxDelta ID="DeltaPlaceHolderMain" IsMainContent="true" runat="server">-->
                        <!--MS:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">-->
                            <div id="overlay">
                                <img alt="" height="548px" src="1414px%20pregancy%20classes.jpg" width="1414px" />
                                <h1>Perinatal Classes Start Today!
                                </h1>
                            </div>7:18 PM 2/18/2017
                        <!--ME:</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>-->
                    <!--ME:</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>-->
                    <!--CE: End PlaceHolderMain Snippet-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <div id="footer">
                <ul>
                    <li>@2017 OLE Health


                    </li>
                    <li>All rights reserved


                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <a href="#">
                        <li>Calistoga


                        </li>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#">
                        <li>County Campus


                        </li>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#">
                        <li>Fairield


                        </li>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#">
                        <li>Napa Pear Tree Lane


                        </li>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#">
                        <li>St. Helena


                        </li>
                    </a>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <a href="#">
                        <li>Integrated Primary Care


                        </li>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#">
                        <li>Behavioral Health


                        </li>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#">
                        <li>Clinical Pharmacy


                        </li>
                    </a>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <a href="#">
                        <li>Submit an IT Ticket


                        </li>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#">
                        <li>Submit a Data Request


                        </li>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#">
                        <li>Submit a Marketing Request


                        </li>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#">
                        <li>
                            <strong>Go back to Homepage


                            </strong>
                        </li>
                    </a>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <img src="Assets/olewhitelogo.png" alt=""/>
                </ul>
        </div>
    </footer>
    </div>
```

```
 #container

{
width: 1414px; 
margin:0 auto;
}


 /* the original body tag had a left and right margin of 10% */


body {
width: 1414px;
margin-left: 10%;
margin-right: 10%;

}
/* CSS Document */

#menu {
width: 1414px;
margin-top: 1%;
padding-bottom: 2%;

}

#menu ul {
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
text-align: center;
 }
 #menu ul li {
background-color: #42A68A;
float: left;
position: relative;
border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
list-style-type: none;
 }
 #menu ul li a {
font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, 
font-size: 14px;
color: #FFFFFF;
display: block;
line-height: 30px;
width: 200px;
height: 30px;
text-decoration: none;
}
  #menu ul ul {
position: absolute;
visibility: hidden;
 }
#menu ul li:hover ul {
visibility: visible;
  }
  #menu ul li:hover  {
background-color: #327E68;
z-index: 1;
 }
 #menu ul li ul li a:hover {
background-color: #119872;
 }
 #menu ul li a:hover {

} 

#pageheader p a:link  {
display: inline-block;
padding: 1em 2em;
background-color: #D93006;
text-decoration: none;
color: #FFFFFF;
float: right;
margin-top: -6%;
font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, 
 }
 #pageheader p a:hover  {
background-color: rgba(175,39,1,1.00);
}
  #pageheader p a:visited  {
color: rgba(255,255,255,1.00);
}
#footer {
position: relative;
clear:left;
width: 500px
background-color: rgba(143,143,143,1.00);
color: #FFFFFF;
font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, 
padding-top: 1%;


}

#footer ul {
position: relative;
float: left;
display: block;
list-style-type: none;
line-height: 255%;
padding-left: 4%;
padding-right: 4%;
}
#footer ul img {
margin-top: 14%;
 }
 #footer ul li {


 }
  #footer ul a:link{
color: rgba(255,255,255,1.00);
text-decoration: none;
text-align: left;

 }
 #footer ul a:visited{
color: rgba(255,255,255,1.00);
text-decoration: none;
text-align: left;

  }
  #footer ul a:hover{
color: rgba(211,211,211,1.00);
text-decoration: none;
text-align: left;



  }
  #footer ul a:link{
color: rgba(255,255,255,1.00);
text-decoration: none;
text-align: left;

}
  #footer ul a:visited{
color: rgba(255,255,255,1.00);
text-decoration: none;
text-align: left;

 }
 #footer ul a:hover{
color: rgba(211,211,211,1.00);
text-decoration: none;
text-align: left;
```

Comment: Is your CSS complete ? Can you restructure it better maybe ?

Comment: If it flickers I would advise checking if something in your JavaScript is not messing with the footer ?

Comment: Hi guys does that help? @NikhilNanjappa

Comment: Check my answer below

Comment: yeah unfortunately that didn't do the trick

Comment: There is still a semicolon missing from `#pageheader p a:link` styles `font-family` property. Can you make sure you have no syntax errors in your CSS first

Answer (score 0):

As I can't see your full code, I can't guess the problem correctly. But I think maybe you can try z-index in your css. Try this:

```
#footer {
  z-index: 10000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things I noticed fixing which would make the footer appear again.

There is a typo at your `#footer` styles, there is semicolon `;` missing after `width: 500px` property and `font-family` property.

```
#footer {
  position: relative;
  clear:left;
  width: 500px // semicolon missing here
  background-color: rgba(143,143,143,1.00);
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana // semicolon missing here
  padding-top: 1%;
}
```

Next if you remove the `float: left` property inside `#footer ul`.

Answer (score -1):

ok.
Now I get it:
1st: do all that  [Nikhil say](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42358428/6666844) and some more miss `;` check all syntax

2nd: chek out colors you have no color for background, but all your blocks use `#ffffff`

**Why it's happening?**

you use `float:left;` in your css.
but for correct use float you need clear `div` at end of container with style `clear:both`. Usually, in css create class `clear` looks like this:

```
.clear {
clear:both;
}
```

and then you can finish your footer like this:

```
      ...
      </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</footer>
 ...
```

This will allow your parent block to fill background color to all his height.
But I can recommend you use `display:flex` instead of `float`. It's much better.